# How to download a scrollable HTML page

Tags: c#, html

I would like to download a webpage from tumblr, so I can scrub it from the images -

https://www.tumblr.com/tagged/otto_schmidt

However (once your logged in), the page continues to load images, as you scroll down further.

What's the best way to download the page in C# so you can scrub it?

Comment: Did you already check [their API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)? Maybe you won't need to scrape the html page at all.

Comment: @Filburt is definitely right, although if that doesn't work out (and there's no reason for it not to), what sort of scrubbing are you looking for? Like, are we talking a straight `HttpWebRequest` kind of console agent, or more like something where a user is able to have some more direct control?

Answer (score 0):

You can you winform webbrowser control, fire document loading complete event.
 Hope this help!